# Apache Kafka Atomic Transactions using Kafka Mirror Maker?

Tags: apache-kafka

We have a system built from multiple Kafka clusters. We have 'raw data' clusters and aggregated clusters. We use Kafka MirrorMaker to consume from the raw data clusters and produce into the aggregated ones.

We are facing issues of message duplication every time we have network issues, even very minor ones. These duplications happen from the MirrorMaker producer.

We wanted to implement idempotency for our MirrorMaker producers. 
We tried adding to the producer config to enable idempotency and to set a transactional.id, but once we start producing we receive this error;

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot perform a 'send' before completing a call to initTransactions when transactions are enabled.
```

Searching online, it seems that we need to enable this initTransactions property in the Producer API itself? Is there a way to tell the Kafka MirrorMaker to initiate this?